# Price convert Mulitple Store

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, multistore

I have 2 multiple Store in site one India and other one US. I have Diiffrent Product Price for particular product in both store.

```
If i have open india store than my indian store product price display. Currently i am gettin US store price for this product. Any one have idea about how to change my price as per store.
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that your website has two store views: India and US, right? and you want to sell a product at different prices in this two store views.

In this case, you cannot set up different prices for a product at the level of website because Magento default does not support it. Therefore, you have to do it at the level of store view

I have seen some similar issues related to various prices for store views and it is suggested using an extension called Multiple store view pricing

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

I also read about it and found out that it can meet your requirement because it allows you to set up different prices for the same product in each store view. By choosing each store view and make adjustments for price, a product will have various prices when displaying in the frontend under corresponding store view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set price per website basis.

you need to go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope.

Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to "Website" instead of global.

Answer (score 0):

Select your website from here.

you need to go to **System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope.**

Then in "Price" tab, set price scope to "Website" from "global".

Comment: It's allready done but still not getting convert price in store.

Comment: So I tried out a few things and found that to set the price on website level one has to select one language (store view) of that website in order to set the price. The price is then set for all store views belonging to that website.